# Particle motion in Center of Momentum frame

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames

I am studying about the *center of momentum* from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center-of-momentum_frame?wprov=sfla1). It is defined as the frame in which the total linear momentum of the system of particles vanishes and that the *center of mass* is but a special case of it. There it is given the following:

If $S$ is the laboratory frame and $S'$ be the *center of momentum* frame. Then, after a Galilean transformation,
$$v'=v-V$$
where $V$ is the velocity of the *center of mass* which, I suppose, is measured in the laboratory frame. Also $v$ be the velocity of a particle in the lab frame. So the above equation must logically mean that $v'$ is the velocity of the particle in the *center of mass* frame. But Wikipedia says that $v'$ is the velocity of particle in the *center of momentum* frame. How can we justify this in a situation where *center of mass* is **not** the same as *center of momentum*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? "In all center-of-momentum frames, the center of mass is at rest, but it is not necessarily at the origin of the coordinate system." In other words: in every center of momentum frame, the center of mass is at rest. But only in the *center of mass* frame is the center of mass also at the *origin*.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I think I get it now. It means that when they are same, both are attached at origin. When they are different, they are at 0 relative speed but at different positions.